# How to write a SQL SELECT query and only select rows that meet a criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help, I'm attempting to write a SQL statement but I only want rows which meet a criteria to be returned. Anything that doesn't meet the criteria, I'd like to ignore and not include in the select.

The criteria is ..

```
loop through each row of the table

if ( physicalpagenum = 0 AND itempagenum = 0)
    keep it in the select

if ( physicalpagenum != itempagenum)
    keep it in the select
```

[image: data example]

I'd have no problems doing this in a object oriented language, I just have no idea how to accomplish it using SQL. Please help. Thanks

Comment: `WHERE (physicalpagenum = 0 AND itempagenum = 0) OR (physicalpagenum <> itempagenum)`

Comment: How will you learn if you don't try? Start with a basic SELECT statement - there are many examples.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with data in a relational database from code written in an object oriented language you are working in two completely different paradigms:

1. Object Oriented paradigm
2. Relational data paradigm

The first is built to model things and perform actions and logic on them and the second, a Relational Database Management System (RDBMS) is built for data storage.

They are optimised for completely different things.

The language of RDBMS's is SQL, SQL is used for Data Definition DDL and for Data Manipulation DML. So you can use it to define your data structures and you can use it to query them and store data in them.

So yes you can iterate over a collection of stuff with a condition in your object oriented world but now you have to learn the Relational Database way of doing it.

So you need to learn SQL

The most basic way to select data from a table, or set of tables is with a SELECT statement:

SELECT [List of columns you want to return] FROM [Table you want it from]
WHERE [Some conditions apply]

But take some time and have a quick go at a basic SQL course online.

Good luck